# How to sort even numbers ascending and odd numbers descending in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know how to sort the odd numbers in descending order on the right of the even ones. I'm kinda stuck here, I know I am missing something.

My output is like this: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

It should be like this: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]`

```js
var n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
n.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a % 2 - b % 2 || b % 2 - a % 2;
});
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial and very expensive solution would be to build two arrays, sort them then concatenate them, but you can combine both tests and sort in place like this:

```
arr.sort((a,b)=> (a%2-b%2) || (a%2 ? b-a : a-b))
```

As you can see, the pattern for hierarchical sort is just

```
arr.sort(compareA || compareB)
```

which you can generalize for more conditions.

```js
let arr = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i)=>i+1)
arr.sort((a,b)=> (a%2-b%2) || (a%2 ? b-a : a-b))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The code doesnot give the correct output. odd numbers should be in descending order

Comment: You probably misunderstood. See the comments what OP said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to get different arrays of even and odd numbers and then sort them and join then using Spread Operator

```js
var n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let odd = n.filter(x => x % 2).sort((a,b) => b-a);

let even = n.filter(x => !(x % 2) ).sort((a,b) => a-b);

let res = [...even,...odd]

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is more expensive than necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the odds and evens and, sort them and finally concatenate both arrays.

```js
let n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let odds = n.filter((a) => a % 2 !== 0).sort((a, b) => b - a);
let even = n.filter((a) => a % 2 === 0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
let sorted = even.concat(odds);
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: OP: *something like this [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]*  -- The odds have to descend as well ..

Comment: thank you so much, this worked for me and I understood where I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you try splitting the array into two arrays (one for even and one for odd) then sort each one as you like and join them back using the spread operator [...even, ...odd]

```
var n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var even = n.filter(a => a % 2 == 0).sort();
var odd = n.filter(a => a % 2 != 0).sort().reverse();
var numbers = [...even, ...odd];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate two array and merge by spread operator.

```
let n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let odd  = n.filter (v => v % 2);
odd.sort((a,b) => b-a);
//console.log(odd)
let even = n.filter (v => !(v % 2));
even.sort((a,b) => a-b);
//console.log(even);

console.log([...even,...odd]);
```

```js
var n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
odd  = n.filter (v => v % 2);
odd.sort((a,b) => b-a);
//console.log(odd)
even = n.filter (v => !(v % 2));
even.sort((a,b) => a-b);
//console.log(even);

console.log([...even,...odd]);
```

Comment: You are declaring implicit global variables. And also there is no difference between mine and your answer. I think you didn't saw mine.

Comment: I updated answer, of course I did not know your answer before

Comment: I removed the downvote. But its not nice to duplicate answers. I am not saying you copied mine. you don't need to. But giving an answer which is exactly same as other is not so nice. Use `let` in your snippet

Comment: when I write code in snippet, it is full screen, I cant see your answer, you should not think like that

Comment: I understand no problem.